# How to properly use typedef for structs in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have a struct for a linked list in my C code. When the list is defined like this:

```
typedef struct LinkedList {
    Ht_item* item;
    LinkedList* next;
}LinkedList;
```

I get the Compilation Error: `"error: unknown type name ‘LinkedList’"` alongside other related error messages

However, when i define my LinkedList this way:

```
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;

struct LinkedList {
    Ht_item* item;
    LinkedList* next;
};
```

I get no errors.

I do not understand why the Error happens in the first instance?

Comment: OT: It's only a special case when a single node is the entire list... Please call a node a "node", and name the variable(s) that point to the head (and tail?) node(s) of the list a "list"... A single "link" is rarely referred to as "a chain"...

Comment: You can't refer to a `typedef` until after the type definition is completed. That's not until the end of the structure definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this definition:

```
typedef struct LinkedList {
    Ht_item* item;
    LinkedList* next;
}LinkedList;
```

You're using the type `LinkedList` before it's been defined or declared.

This works:

```
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;

struct LinkedList {
    Ht_item* item;
    LinkedList* next;
};
```

Because `LinkedList` has been declared (but not fully defined) by the time it's used, and because you're creating a pointer to that type it doesn't need to be fully defined yet.

This would also work:

```
typedef struct LinkedList {
    Ht_item* item;
    struct LinkedList* next;
}LinkedList;
```

For the same reason the prior piece of code works.